# SMTP, snort: warning 124:3 attempted response buffer overflow

Tags: smtp, snort

From time to time, I'm receiving a 124:3 warning "attempted response buffer overflow" from SNORT, while sending emails.
What could cause this warning? How can it be investigated? How can it be solved?

Notes:

- unfortunately, the SMTP server and its configuration is out of my scope, so I cannot provide further details.
- The client used to send the email is an instance of [`EmailOperator` from `airflow.operators.email_operator`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.4.3/_api/airflow/operators/email/index.html) in **Airflow 2.4.3** ( https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow/2.4.3/ ); the mail is sent specifying host, user and password in Airflow's configuration. About the Email operator, see: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.1/_modules/airflow/operators/email_operator.html

References:

https://www.snort.org/rule_docs/124-3

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/secure-firewall/snort3-inspectors/snort-3-inspector-reference/smtp-inspector.html

Comment: What software is generating the line? How is it configured? What line length have you configured to trigger that warning?

Comment: Unfortunately, the SMTP server and its configuration is out of my scope, so I cannot provide further details (I just edited the question, specifying that).

Comment: In that case, what client software is initiating the SMTP session? How is it configured? What does the line look like? Why is it readable for snort in the first place, instead of transmitted via a secure channel?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The client is actually an instance of EmailOperator from airflow.operators.email_operator in Airflow 2.4.3, https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow/2.4.3/ . The mail is sent specifying host, user and password (I just added this note to the question).